# SQL Server Integer to Time

Tags: sql-server, converters, sql-timestamp

I came into a scenario where table containing the time values in integer datatype and I need to convert them to `TIME` datatype to use `DATEDIFF()` function.

Ex: if column value is 449, then it's 04:49:00:00; if the column contains 25, then 02:05:00:00.

If anyone has a user-defined procedure or code that should be more helpful to use them in `Select` statement as I need to pass this value to `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: 25 -> 02:05 looks inconsistent with 449-> 04:49. Can you provide more examples?

Comment: This dies not solve the 25 >> 2:05.  I suspect a typo.  Otherwise try  Select  timefromparts(449/100 ,449%100 ,0 ,0,0 )

Comment: Ignoring that 25 somehow becomes 02:05:00.000, this sounds like the silly encodings used in `run_date` and `run_time` in the Jobs tables in msdb. In that case there's an undocumented function that turns those values back into a `datetime` value, `msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS!!!!!

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfConv(
    @quantity INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(@quantity)=2 THEN '0'+LEFT(@quantity,1) +':'+'0'+RIGHT(@quantity,1)+':00:00'
            WHEN LEN(@quantity)=3 THEN '0'+LEFT(@quantity,1) +':'+RIGHT(@quantity,2)+':00:00'
            WHEN LEN(@quantity)=4 THEN LEFT(@quantity,2) +':'+RIGHT(@quantity,2)+':00:00'
 END AS TIME))
END;
```

THIS IS NOT EXACT THE DATETIME FORMAT. DATETIME FORMAT IS SOMETHING LIKE DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM: SS. HOWEVER, THIS QUESTION NEEDS MORE IMPROVEMENT.